# Something invisible outside div image blocking mouseover on other one

Tags: html, css, mouseover

RighteousAlliance.com - two buttons on the right with mouseover effects. (i'll fix their actual position later)

If you adjust the browser width by dragging it you notice how they stay in the same position relative to the background?  That's what I want.

But there's something invisible outside the images that are overlapping and ruining the mouseover effect.  If you hover vertically over "shop" you notice how it only lights up ABOVE the top part of "Learn" to the right?

What is blocking that??  There's something invisible outside the div.  I've tried for 3 days to figure this out.

I can fix that problem by adding "display: inline-block" and something else.  BUT THEN IT BREAKS THE ALIGNMENT WITH THE BACKGROUND when you adjust the browser size horizontally.  How do I get BOTH to work?  Please help.  I did it a long time ago but can't figure it out.

Here's a screenshot of the code:  https://righteousalliance.com/Images/code.png

Comment: So, there's multiple issues in there like invalid properties, improper tag use etc, but if you only want to address the issue of not being able to hover the "shop" button for now....well the div it sits in `id="learn"` is what's taking your mouseover. So if you add `pointer-events: none` to your `#learn` css you'll have your hover back. However I would suggest addressing the other issues also before building more on to it or issues like these will only quantify. Also, generally just giving a link isn't a proper example but welcome to SO, Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much Chris.  I'll look at it more closely then and try that.